# What's the basis of conditional statements in comparing expressions?

Tags: c++, c

I have this confusion about conditional statements which may be applicable to almost all programming languages.
Like for instance this C++ code:

```
int main()
{
   char *ptr, arr[]={'C','O','M','P','I','L','E','R','\0'};
   ptr = arr;
   *ptr = 'Z';
   while(*ptr++)
    cout << *(ptr-1);

   return 0;
}
```

As what I have learned, a conditional statement executes only when the expression is true. So in this case, this part:

```
while(*ptr++)
```

The compiler considers all the characters being true except for the NULL. So meaning to say only NULL is false in this case? And it's alright to do this with characters?:

```
if('x'){do something}
```

Comment: The expression inside the while, (*ptr++) is evaluated, *ptr is a char, which is evaluated as a number (integer), and will be >0 until the character pointed to by *ptr is the null terminator, '\0'.

Comment: Both C and C++ look at the character as a number (the ordinal value of the character), which is !=0 unless it is the null terminator.  Be careful btw, as char is signed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(*ptr++)
```

will keep going till the time ptr does not point to the end of this string which is `\0` (Null Terminator) , This same statement also increments ptr to point to next value on each run, so essentially its saying `while this condition is true`, keep going. And the condition is `while ptr still points to an element of arr`;

> In C++, the definition of NULL is 0, so there is only an aesthetic difference. I prefer to avoid macros, so I use 0. Another problem with NULL is that people sometimes mistakenly believe that it is different from 0 and/or not an integer. In pre-standard code, NULL was/is sometimes defined to something unsuitable and therefore had/has to be avoided. That's less common these days.

**[Reference](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null)**

**Edit:**

> But why is it accepting arguments like: while('x')? A letter 'x' is true?

No it doesn't mean the letter itself is true, it means that its not NULL, which is 0. Consider it like this.

```
while('x')
```

is the equivalent of saying

```
while('x'!=0)    // so that is perfectly acceptable and understandable
```

**Edit 2:**

Here is a simpler example for you to be able to better understand

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
   int x=0;

   if(x)
   {
     cout<<"If this is shown, x was not 0.";
   }
   if(x==0)
   {
     cout<<"so does it mean x is true? no: It means your condition 'x==0' is true";
   }
}
```

Comment: But why is it accepting arguments like: `while('x')`? A letter 'x' is true? I mean what's the basis to make it true?

Comment: See edit 2 as well, it has an example for you

Answer (score 0):

In C, any number apart from 0 is considered true. (0 is false)
If you iterate over an array with *prt++, it checks if the currect index is not zero and increases the pointer.

if `('x')` is perfectly valid, but it will always be considered true.

(Remember that char internally is but an 8 bit number and 0 is used to terminate strings. In the example you provided, it is used to iterate over the "string")

And yes, NULL is also considered false (because the address the pointer points to is 0), however, in the example you provided, the pointer gets dereferenced first, so it checks at the place it points to.

Answer (score 0):

It is a relic of C that anything non-zero will evaluate to a boolean true when it is tested, such as your `if ('x')` above.  x has an integer value as it is a character of non-zero value, therefore the expression would evaluate true.

In the case of the pointer iterating over the character array, C 'strings' are always ended in '\0', null, which when the pointer gets there will be the time where the while will fail as null == 0.  Not to be confused with '0' as '0' is a character and has an integer value.